# How does one find element by text and then copy the next sibling element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to learn python selenium and I have been stuck for days trying to figure out the best way for me to extract only the date from this little chunk of code. My best guess was to

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH text()contains 'registration date' blah
```

then somehow find the next element that comes directly after that, but every time I retrieve the element from the page it gives it to me in the form of:

```
element="37253116-f015-40a1-bdb1-135342333393"
```

but I haven't the slightest clue about what that even is - let alone what I could do with it.

Also, Pandas doesn't recognize this chunk of code as a table and ignores it when looking for tables, sadly. If anybody has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated.. Unless it's by making a loop in Beautiful Soup..

```
<dl class="space">
    <dt>MASTER NAME</dt>
    <dd>Napoleon</dd>
    <dt>BUSINESS TYPE</dt>
    <dd>Oxygen farm</dd>
    <dt>FILE NUMBER</dt>
    <dd>94785394</dd>
    <dt>STATUS</dt>
    <dd>Active</dd>
    <dt>PURPOSE</dt>
    <dd> relaxation </dd>
    <dt>PLACE INCORPORATED</dt>
    <dd> the moon </dd>
    <dt>REGISTRATION DATE</dt>
    <dd>Dec 8, 1986</dd>
    <dt>MAILING ADDRESS</dt>
    <dd> fun land <br>
    THE MOON 
</dd>
              </dl>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for us to help you, please create a [mcve] and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: Post the url and the code that you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this xpath should work for you - it will return you the first sibling of the *Registration date* **dt** element:

```
//dl[@class = 'space']/dt[text() = 'REGISTRATION DATE']/following-sibling::dd[1]
```

and then you can call the method for fetching the text of this found element

Comment: That's seems like it's exactly what I need, and it's incredible, but am I calling it incorrectly?

I currently have it as 
`date = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//dl[@class = 'space']/dt[text() = 'REGISTRATION DATE']/following-sibling::dd[1]")

print(date)`
But when I do that it only prints:
`<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e4cb4eda7d0e247592306f5df9551c74", element="65fcd644-5ee6-4f12-8982-eb6bf9617fb2")>`

Comment: Scratch that, all along it was as simple as adding ".text" to the end of either the "date = ..." line, or adding ".text" while printing as:  print(date.text). You're a life saver Marek, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

suppose you want the code similar as the following, locate one element by xpath, and then iterate the next sibling element

```
from clicknium import clicknium as cc

if not cc.chrome.extension.is_installed():
    cc.chrome.extension.install_or_update()
tab = cc.chrome.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=clicknium")
elem = tab.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="b_results"]/li[2]')

while elem != None:
    print(elem.get_text())
    elem = elem.next_sibling
```